# Unset terms that show in taxonomy autocomplete

Tags: 7

I would like to unset terms that show up in taxonomy autocomplete.

For example if TID 1 2 3 4, are in the taxonomy I would only like 1 2 and 3 to show in the dropdown for autocomplete.

Comment: have you look at this mudule? https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_autocomplete_settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to alter the query but according to a comment there is no alter tag set on the query

-
 https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7.x
- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.pages.inc/function/taxonomy_autocomplete/7.x

Another solution would be to alter the form with the autocomplete field to alter the path

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x
- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#autocomplete_path

iirc as a last resort you could use javascript to drop the unwanted item from the list using css display:none

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to create your own autocomplete path. Here are the steps to implement this:

Create a custom module

In hook menu create a custom autocomplete path:

```
$items['my-module-taxonomy/autocomplete'] = array(
  'title' => 'Custom Autocomplete taxonomy',
  'page callback' => 'my_module_taxonomy_autocomplete',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Create my_module_taxonomy_autocomplete function.  The easy way would be to copy everything from the  taxonomy_autocomplete() function and add conditions in your query. For example:

```
->condition('t.tid', array(1,2,3), 'IN')
```

In hook_form_alter() set the autocomplete field from using the default one to the custom one you just made:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'my_node') {
    $form['field_term'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#autocomplete_path'] = 'my-module-taxonomy/autocomplete';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**

Use an Entity Reference field to reference taxonomy terms filtered by an entity reference view.

**Method**

1. Create a View showing "Taxonomy terms" of type "vocabulary name"
2. Add a Views display of type "Entity Reference"
3. Under "Format" next to "Entity Reference list" click "Settings" and select relevant "Search fields"
4. Add any filters under "Filter criteria", such as "Taxonomy term: Term ID"
5. For "Operator" in step 4, select "Is not equal to" or "Is less than" for example. See below.
6. Save the view.
7. Add an "Entity reference" field to your entity with "Target type" of "Taxonomy term" and select your "Target bundles"
8. For "Mode" under "Entity selection", select "Views: filter by an entity reference view"
9. Select the "View used to select the entities"
10. Provide any arguments if required and review other field options.
11. Save the field settings.

**Example**

In your example, for step 5 you could add a single filter for "Taxonomy term: Term ID":

**Operator:** Is less than

**Value:** 4

You can add as many filters as you like and even [perform calculations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc_filter) if required.

More filter options are available via custom code or contributed modules such as 
[Code Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/codefilter) which allows the use of PHP. See also [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) and [Global Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter).